# jquery remove and addclass doesn't work on iphone

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs. One is the label div, the other one is the input div. When I toggle the label div, the input div is toggling. I am also closing the input div by clicking anywhere on the screen. Everything works fine, but nothing works on an iPhone.

```css
. yoket {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var label = $("#semt");
  var container1 = $("#semt1");

  if (label.has(e.target).length === 1) {
    if (container1.hasClass("yoket")) {
      container1.removeClass("yoket");
    } else if (!container1.hasClass("yoket")) {
      container1.addClass("yoket");
    }
  } else if (container1.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container1.addClass("yoket");
  }
});
```

Comment: is the space in the css class selector intentional ? (`. yoket`)

Comment: why do you have a space in this? `. yoket`

Comment: ignore it, it's just to show you what is "yoket"

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working for mobile(or any touch based device) is because the mouseup event is not fired, Please switch to click and/or touchend events to it. Ideally this should work.

```
$(document).bind("mouseup touchend",function(e) {
  var label = $("#semt");
  var container1 = $("#semt1");

  if (label.has(e.target).length === 1) {
    if (container1.hasClass("yoket")) {
      container1.removeClass("yoket");
    } else if (!container1.hasClass("yoket")) {
      container1.addClass("yoket");
    }
  } else if (container1.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container1.addClass("yoket");
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!